# Retaining XML Nodes Containing String Matches with R - Webscraping

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

I'm trying to filter and keep only the nodes containing certain string matches using R/XML. I've collected the text I'm looking for on a webpage, but I just want to filter down the remaining nodes to keep before cleaning them up.  Here is a sample of two of the nodes:

```
<tr>\n<td>Fiscal Year End:</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="right-align">Oct 
<tr>\n<td>Term:</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="right-align">No</td>\r\n\t\
```

Because "Fiscal Year End" is in one of the nodes, and "Term" is in another, I want to keep both (as well as other nodes containing string matches).  The XMLM object is called "paragraph".  Much appreciate any help here as I'm a bit rusty!

Comment: When it comes to scraping, rvest package would probably serve you better than plain xml. Comes with `rvest::html_table()` to parse HTML tables.

Comment: Is there a public url? How many other strings have to be matched upon and do they also appear within tr/td elements?

Comment: Yes here is an example showing the structure of the webpage: https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/GDL

Comment: I found  under Fund Basics. What exactly do you need? All of that section "Basics"  under Fund Management?

Comment: Click the tabel labeled "All" and you'll see the "Term" field.  Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Ok. So what do you need from this page? Only those two lines?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like all fields from the tables on the page presented in a two column-wise vectors: the field (i.e. Category or Ticker) and it's corresponding value.  Much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(stringr)

my_String <- c('<tr>\n<td>Fiscal Year End:</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="right-align">Oct',
               '<tr>\n<td>Term:</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class="right-align">No</td>\r\n\t')

stringr::str_replace_all(my_String,
                         pattern = "<tr>|<td>|\\n|\\r|\\t|<td class=\"right-align\">|</td>", 
                         replacement = "")

[1] "Fiscal Year End:Oct" "Term:No"
```